# Optional regex match is being ignored

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a bit of regex in PHP that isn't doing what I want it to.

What I want:

```
[segment type="segment_name"]more text here[/segment]
```

to be changed to:

```
[segmentclass='segment_name segment']more text here[/segment]
```

and:

```
[segment]more text here[/segment]
```

to be changed to:

```
[segmentclass=' segment']more text here[/segment]
```

Here is what I have:

```
$pattern = '/(\[segment.*?)(type=\"(.+?)\")?(.*?\[\/segment\])/is';
$replacement = '$1class=\'$3 segment\'$4';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? The ? after (type=\"(.+?)\") is to make that block optional. It seems like the replace is just skipping it because it's optional. I think I have a problem with greediness somewhere but I haven't been able to sort it out.

Please reply if you have any ideas for another way I could do this as well.

Comment: You don't appear to have the closing `]` in your pattern anywhere.

Comment: That should be alright getting matched with the second .*? and then included in $4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no closing bracket `]` for the first segment block. Because it finds no match for that closing block, `.*?` matches everything up to `[/segment]`, ignoring the optional group you put in there.

You should avoid using `.*` in any form if you can, and this is a classic situation where a negating character class would be approriate. `[^\]]*` is be the better choice.

The reason why that character class would be a better choice here is that it would make the regex fail, instead of giving you a false positive.

The input you have listed in your question, as well as your specific matching of `segment` makes me believe your regex is overly complicated as well, and the replacement is very messy. This updated regex also does not need the DOTALL flag.

```
$pattern = '/\[segment(?: type="([^"]+)")?\]/i';
$replacement = '[segmentclass=\'$1 segment\']';
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to match the ] because the $3 I want is before the ]. This set me on the path of trying to get the .* to be better. Apparently the . wasn't matching the space. I changed it to [ .]* and now it works. I'll try to work on a better character class. Thanks.

Comment: In your sample text, nothing really specifies that you should need the .*? after the opening segment. I've updated the answer to reflect my thoughts.